# How to close a PHP page invoked by QR Code?

Tags: php, qr-code

I created a QR code that invokes a pure PHP page to perform database updates.  I currently testing with the iPhone camera and it does trigger backend operations as expected.  The question is when the QR code is scanned, it brings up a blank page.  Is it possible to close this blank page by itself at the end of back-end operations or at least not to open a new blank page every time but remain on the same blank page for every new scan?

Comment: Closing a page is a client-side action, while PHP is server-side scripting. You should look for JavaScript implementation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.close() in javascript if your page is created by window.open(). Otherwise, it is not possible to close a page from client side.

If you don't want your users to see a blank page you can redirect them to another page after operation has been done. Use header function in php.

```php
header('Location: http://localhost/');
```

Comment: The window is created by scanning a QR code.  I tried to use window.close() but it didn't work so I guess that is not treated as created by windows.open().  The main reason I want to close it is because there will be many times of calling that php page but with different query string by QR code scanning, therefore I don't want user to have dozen of blank pages opened every day.

Answer (score 0):

A QR code doesn't "invoke" anything, it encodes some text.

If you're writing a custom app, that text can be anything you like, and trigger any behaviour you like.

If the text you encode is a URL, that URL can be opened in a web browser. It will behave exactly the same as if the user had clicked a link to it, or typed it into their web browser. You have only the same control of that browser as any other website, and that doesn't include managing their tabs for them - you weren't responsible for creating the tab, so have no power to close it.

Indeed, the user can look at the URL and share it around, edit it, or be tricked into visiting it by someone else. Make sure you understand the security implications of this! You might want to make the URL load a page with a button on, which submits a POST form, which can't be bookmarked etc; read up on techniques to avoid "CSRF attacks".

What you can and should do is make the page not blank - write a "thank you" message, or redirect the user somewhere else, once the action has completed.

Comment: Sounds like it is impossible to close it.  What about if it is possible to remain on the same tab as the URL is the same except the query string will be different (i.e. www.domain.com/page?id=1, id=2 and so on).  If this is possible then the user wouldn't have dozen of tabs open.

Comment: @JimW By the time any of your code runs, the tab is already open. That's why I emphasised that it's not the QR code that runs anything - imagine the user has pressed "new tab" and typed in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  One thing I don't understand is the difference between the URL has and has no query string.  I added <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);</script>to the end of the script. It does close the tab by itself when there is no query string (Note: I only tested it by pasting the URL onto the address bar)